# C++ Non-Abstract Destructor Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11

I've seen this asked before, but not clearly or in the same situation as I have encountered.

I have an abstract base class. It has a protected constructor and a destructor. It is inherited by several complete types which also have public constructors and destructors. I'm having the issue where deleting the object isn't calling the child destructors if the object is referenced by the base type.

```
class Tree
{
protected:
        Tree(){ }
public:
        ~Tree(){ }
};

class OakTree : public Tree
{
public:
        OakTree(){ }
        ~OakTree(){ }
};

vector<Tree*> Trees; // Store objects using the base type
Trees.push_back(new OakTree()); // Create derived object
delete Trees[0]; // OakTree desctructor does not get called
```

How can I get the OakTree destructor called? I've tried marking all of the destructors to virtual but that didn't work. The base class destructor cannot be abstract (this would solve the calling problem but not the delete problem).

Comment: Sorry, I had an error within one of the destructors causing it to show a memory leak on my memory dump making me think the destructor wasn't called. I was 99% sure the destructors should have been virtual in this case, but I put them as virtual but that didn't fix my memory leak problem. Careless on my part but +1 for your answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make your base-class destructor `virtual`.

```
class Tree
{
protected:
        Tree(){ }
public:
        virtual ~Tree(){ }
}
```

Otherwise, undefined behavior will result if you try to delete through a base-class pointer. It's a bit dated, but Scott Meyers expressed this colorfully in *Effective C++*, 2nd ed:

> The C++ language standard is unusually clear on this topic: when you try to delete a derived class object through a base class pointer and the base class has a *nonvirtual* destructor (as `EnemyTarget` does), the results are undefined. This means compilers may generate code to do whatever they like: reformat your disk, send suggestive mail to your boss, fax source code to your competitors, whatever. (What often happens at runtime is that the derived class's destrutcor is never called. ...)

Comment: That would actually be implementation specific, and I am fairly certain existing implementations don't call functions at random, especially such formatting disk drives. The compilers I've tested call the "closest thing", which is the destructor for the pointer T.

Comment: This is *hyperbole*. However, undefined behavior can be a security risk, which in some cases can be exploited to accomplish a variety of attackers' goals.

Comment: Just don't think hyperbole has any place in technical literature, me thinks Mr Mayers tries too hard to be "eccentric"/funny and unnecessarily colorful in many of his statements. I've grown to hate this kind of behavior due to attention craving professors at lectures who tend to spend more time on cultivating fancy image in front of "impressionable youth" than actually teaching the subject at hand.

Comment: Meyers is not alone. In C/C++ discussions, you will also encounter references to demons flying out of your nose, or monkeys flying out of a less pleasant location. These are also hyperbole. It's intended to create a lasting impression of just how undesirable is undefined behavior.

Comment: Didn't quite work in this manner for me. More like appeared as showcasing of lame sense of humor. Maybe I am just a tad more pragmatic, but it seems kind of paradoxical to stress the severity and importance of something by means of making jokes about it. If you are indeed right and they do it for the sake of education, why is that after making such statements, they always have a self satisfied, expecting applauds, laughter and admiration look on their faces when they do that live?

Comment: @ddriver it is not implementation-specific, it is undefined. Just because the specific test cases you ran on some particular compiler/platform/version/optimization gave one result doesn't mean another piece of code would experience the same result. It's true that compilers aren't calling malicious easter eggs on UB, but with the optimizer's preconditions violated, other things can happen, and not necessarily on this line of code.

Comment: @Cubbi - it is undefined behavior by standard, but the particular implementations definitely define a behavior, it is not some "launch arbitrary routine" thing. I am yet to see a case of something else besides calling the destructor for the pointer/ref type. If you have an example case, do share.

Answer (score 3):

It's because your base class destructor is not declared virtual.

```
class Tree
{
protected:
        Tree(){ }
public:
        virtual ~Tree(){ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use polymorphism you have to have a virtual destructor in your base class.

The problem is that when you call delete on a `Tree *` nobody really knows what kind of tree it is, and by having a virtual destructor the compiler generates a call through the pointer that points to the table for functions for that particular object instance, and you get the destructor for whatever that type might be.

Otherwise the standard says it is undefined behavior, but what seems to happen most of the times is the compiler generates a call to the destructor of whatever type your polymorphic pointer or reference is, in your case, that is the base class.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder why nobody is actually asking what the author is trying to achieve with the code?

While, yes, having a virtual destructor in the base class will help you to get your destructor called, what you're still left with is *undefined behavior*.

What do you expect after the line `delete Trees[0];`?

Or, rather, what are you trying to achieve with that line?

If you're trying to erase the item from the vector, you might want:

```
Trees.erase(Trees.begin());
```

But then, you're left with the memory leak if you *forget* the delete line.

Hence, don't use plain pointers in your vector. Consider:

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Tree> > Trees;
Trees.push_back( std::make_shared<OakTree>() );
Trees.erase(Trees.begin());
```

Runnable [@Ideone](http://ideone.com/h2hZW3)

Comment: This is simplified code from a larger project. The base class stores some data and the derived classes manipulate that data is various ways. The derived classes also have local resources that need to be deleted at the end of the lifespan of the object. I am aware of how vectors work, and that was not part of the question.

Comment: what about memory management? If it only were for the destructor, you don't need any vector code in your question

Comment: Just to call attention to the fact that I'm storing it as `Tree*` and not `OakTree*` or `Tree`. Let's not get too nit-picky. The question is answered.